# Inserting a line in a file only if this line isn't yet part of the file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, grep

I am searching to create a script to automatically apply some custom configuration to text based configuration files.

In the present case, I am searching to add 2 line to `/etc/sysctl.conf` if these line are not yet in the file (to avoid having multiple occurrence of these line in the file).

here is the script I use :

```
if [ `grep vm.swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf` != "vm.swappiness=5" ]; then
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
fi
if [ `grep vm.vfs_cache_pressure /etc/sysctl.conf` != "vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50" ]; then
echo vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
fi
```

and the error I get :

```
/home/erwan/Workspace/Install.sh: ligne 19 : [: != : opérateur unaire attendu
/home/erwan/Workspace/Install.sh: ligne 23 : [: != : opérateur unaire attendu
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI it's not *Linux scripting*, it's *shell scripting*, or (e.g.) *bash scripting*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a problem:

```
if [ `grep vm.swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf` != "vm.swappiness=5" ]; then
```

Since if `grep` doesn't find anything, it doesn't output anything, and the left hand side of this will be nothing, which is an error.  It's also a problem if it does find something, since the output could contain whitespace (e.g., if `vm.swappiness` is in the file multiple times).  That needs to be quoted, or it will appear as a series of distinct strings when expanded.

You should thus use `if [ "$(grep ...)" ]` so the output is quoted.  If there is no output, you have `""`, which is fine on either side of a test in bash.

However, in this case I'd recommend using the [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of grep instead.  From `man grep`:

> EXIT STATUS
>
> Normally, the exit status is 0 if selected lines are found and 1 otherwise.  But the exit status is 2 if  an  error  occurred...

Also usefule here is the `-q` switch:

> -q, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet;  do  not  write  anything to standard output.  Exit immediately **with zero status** if any match is found, even if an
>   error was detected.

So, keeping in mind `$?` is the exit status of the last completed foreground process:

```
grep -q grep vm.vfs_cache_pressure /etc/sysctl.conf
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
```

This condition will be true if `grep` did not find anything, and no error occurred.

Comment: `if` works on the command directly, so you can even just write it as `if ! grep -q not_found /etc/sysctl.conf; then ...;fi`.

Comment: @h.j.k The problem with that here is that the test is actually to see if grep *failed* to find anything -- but *we also want to exclude fail on error*...in the former case it returns 1, in the later 2.  We want only the former. I.e. it's "if grep did not encounter errors or find a match".  Going that route, it might be good to use a `case` or `elif` to report any errors.

Comment: ah I see, that's clearer and makes sense now. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

It could be because your `grep` is not returning anything.  As it isn't quoted, then you get that error message (unary operator expected).  Try:-

```
if [ "$(grep vm.swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf)" != "vm.swappiness=5" ]; then
```

Comment: It worked, but goldilocks explained it better. I give you an upvote anyway

Answer (score 4):

Just for inspirational purposes, needs some tweaking maybe:

```
#assuming there is only one line with vm.swappiness
#otherwise you can use the test command with "grep -c vm.swappiness" first
#tests if the correct line is in the file
if grep -q -E '^vm.swappiness=5$' /etc/sysctl.conf; then
    echo "all good, do nothing";
else
    echo "removing possible lines with vm.swappiness"
    sudo sed -i '/^vm.swappiness=/d' /etc/sysctl.conf 
    echo "adding line with correct swappiness"
    sudo bash -c "echo 'vm.swappiness=5' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
fi
```

Also wrapping this in a function might be good, so you can call it with your next parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work:

```
f=/etc/sysctl.conf
[ -w "$f" ] || exit 1
for line in 'vm.swappiness=5' 'vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50' ; do
    grep -q "$line" <"$f" || printf %s\\n "$line"
done >>"$f"
```

You should probably get `sudo` out of that script, too. If needed run the script *with* `sudo` like `sudo ./script.sh` and keep it as a separate module from other scripts. Else do:

```
sudo sh -c '
    f=/etc/sysctl.conf
    [ -w "$f" ] || exit 1
    for line in "vm.swappiness=5" "vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50" ; do
        grep -q "$line" <"$f" || printf %s\\n "$line"
    done >>"$f"
'
```

But I don't recommend it.